# MYSQL select from child categories

Tags: php, mysql, parent-child

Trying to get products a couple of levels down the tree... It's not working.

SELECT `Products`.*
                FROM        `Products`

```
            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C
                ON  `Products`.`Category_ID` = C.`ID`
                OR  `Products`.`Sub_Category_ID` = C.`ID`
                OR  `Products`.`Sub_Category2_ID` = C.`ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C2
                ON      C.`ID` = C2.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C3
                ON      C2.`ID` = C3.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C4
                ON      C3.`ID` = C4.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C5
                ON      C4.`ID` = C5.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C6
                ON      C5.`ID` = C6.`Parent_ID`

            WHERE       `Products`.`Is_Master_Product` = 'Yes'
                AND     `Products`.`Is_Published` = 'Yes'
                AND     (`Products`.`Category_ID` = '29'
                        OR      `Products`.`Sub_Category_ID` = '29'
                    OR      `Products`.`Sub_Category2_ID` = '29')
            GROUP BY    `Products`.`Name`
            ORDER BY    `Products`.`Name` ASC
```

Comment: And how is this not working?

Comment: Doesn't return any products. Category 29 doesn't have any direct products, but category 58 does have products in it. Category 58's Parent_ID = 29

Comment: . . Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/wSPGE6C.png?1)

Comment: Should return just 1 row, the one with Is_Master_Product

Comment: @GordonLinoff Here's the categories in question [link](http://i.imgur.com/0MeKyaD.png?1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Products`.*
            FROM        `Products`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C
                ON  `Products`.`Category_ID` = C.`ID`
                OR  `Products`.`Sub_Category_ID` = C.`ID`
                OR  `Products`.`Sub_Category2_ID` = C.`ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C2
                ON      C.`ID` = C2.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C3
                ON      C2.`ID` = C3.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C4
                ON      C3.`ID` = C4.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C5
                ON      C4.`ID` = C5.`Parent_ID`

            LEFT JOIN   `Product_Categories` C6
                ON      C5.`ID` = C6.`Parent_ID`

            WHERE       `Products`.`Is_Master_Product` = 'Yes'
                AND     `Products`.`Is_Published` = 'Yes'
                AND     (C.`Parent_ID` = '$category_ID'
                    OR  C.`ID` = '$category_ID')
            GROUP BY    `Products`.`Name`
            ORDER BY    `Products`.`Name` ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

Give table schema, sample data.
Maybe stored procedure will be better aproach ?

Comment: This is appropriate as a comment, but not as an answer.